Only one CIFS share is auto-mounted
I have the following two mounts listed in my /etc/fstab
//192.168.10.1/StashNas /mnt/stashnas cifs uid=sam,gid=sam,credentials=/etc/stashnas.credentials 0 0
//192.168.10.1/StashSam /mnt/stashsam cifs uid=sam,gid=sam,credentials=/etc/stashnas.credentials 0 0

After booting, /mnt/stashsam is mounted as expected, but /mnt/stashnas is not. Running sudo mount -a will mount /mnt/stashnas. Why doesn't the first mount happen at boot time?
System Info:
sam@stash-pc:~[main]$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
sam@stash-pc:~[main]$ uname -a
Linux stash-pc 6.8.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 20 15:51:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


I can't pinpoint the exact issue unfortunately, but I had a similar issue with two NFS shares on my NAS (neither of them would mount at boot time OR both would mount at boot time), so maybe this won't help in this specific case, but I think you'll still want to add _netdev to your mount options, so that the mounts will be considered network mounts and so that mounting will be attempted only after the network is up.

@kos Found the solution (See answer). Not sure it was related to your problem. I tried _netdev as well, but I think because they are cifs shares, that option is already implied.

I found the problem.
First I was able to check the boot log to get more info with
sudo less -R /var/log/boot.log.1

(There are many boot.log files kept in that directy, boot.log was empty)
This gave an actual helpful error message:
[***   ] Job mnt-stashnas.mount/start running (8s / 1min 36s)
^M[ ***  ] Job mnt-stashnas.mount/start running (9s / 1min 36s)
^M         Starting colord.service - Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
[  OK  ] Started colord.service - Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
[FAILED] Failed to mount mnt-stashnas.mount - Mount StashNas.
See 'systemctl status mnt-stashnas.mount' for details.

Systemctl printed out this:
sam@stash-pc:~[main]$ sudo systemctl status mnt-stashnas.mount 
× mnt-stashnas.mount - Mount StashNas
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-stashnas.mount; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-06-13 19:19:34 PDT; 3min 37s ago
      Where: /mnt/stashnas
       What: freenas.local:/mnt/PrimaryVolume/StashNas/
        CPU: 5ms

This was curious because the drive was definitely not mounted as freenas.local:/... (See /etc/fstab in question above)
Turns out there was a relatively ancient systemd service to mount the same drive at the same path from 2019
sam@stash-pc:~[main]$ sudo ls -la /etc/systemd/system/mnt-stashnas.mount 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200 Aug 26  2019 /etc/systemd/system/mnt-stashnas.mount

Deleting that service (and sudo systemctl daemon-reload) and now systemd is using the correct fstab generated mount service for both shares:
sam@stash-pc:~[main]$ sudo systemctl status mnt-stashnas.mount 
● mnt-stashnas.mount - /mnt/stashnas
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
     Active: active (mounted) since Thu 2024-06-13 19:24:11 PDT; 5s ago
      Where: /mnt/stashnas
       What: //192.168.10.1/StashNas
       Docs: man:fstab(5)
             man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
        CPU: 5ms
sam@stash-pc:~[main]$ sudo systemctl status mnt-stashsam.mount 
● mnt-stashsam.mount - /mnt/stashsam
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
     Active: active (mounted) since Thu 2024-06-13 19:19:29 PDT; 5min ago
      Where: /mnt/stashsam
       What: //192.168.10.1/StashSam
       Docs: man:fstab(5)
             man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 38331)
     Memory: 72.0K (peak: 1.8M)
        CPU: 10ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-stashsam.mount

TL;DR: There was already a (custom - written by me years ago) systemd service that was mounting the drive improperly. Because there was already a mnt service defined to mount the drive, systemd did not use the settings in /etc/fstab. Deleting the old systemd unit file, and reloading the systemd daemon fixed it.
